# How to get the value if exists before doing groupby

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing ID and type, I want to get the distinct rows of the ID, however, I want to get the type if it exists by a certain value.

For example:

| ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NOT ANSWERED |
| 1 | ANSWERED |
| 1 | NOT ANSWERED |
| 2 | NOT ANSWERED |
| 3 | ANSWERED |

"ANSWERED" should be selected if it exists at least once for the certain ID.

The expected result should be the following:

| ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ANSWERED |
| 2 | NOT ANSWERED |
| 3 | ANSWERED |

How can this be done in an efficient way mentioning that the table contains millions of rows?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: "ANSWERED" should be selected if it exists at least once for the certain ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.type = 'ANSWERED'
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.type = 'ANSWERED')
```

Or, with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ID, COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'ANSWERED' THEN type END), 'NOT ANSWERED') type
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
```

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
       FIRST_VALUE(type) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY type = 'ANSWERED' DESC) type
FROM tablename
```

Another solution that works only because `'ANSWERED'` is less alphabetically than `'NOT ANSWERED'`:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(type) type
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2dd0418f9ed4da204d077e7bad93442).

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @MuhammadNe fine if it worked. Check also my 3d query if you have MySql 8.0+